# std.algorithm.sorting fails with obscure errors when using Array!T and opSlice()

Tags: arrays, sorting, d, phobos

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here - the rest of D (even the compiler errors) have been very sensible and easy to understand. I have a `std.containers.Array` of comparable structs and I'd like to sort it. the `std.containers` documentation notes that in order to use the stuff in `std.algorithm` you need to slice it, either with `array[]` or `array.opSlice()`. Okay, no problem.

However, if I make an `Array` of two pretty trivial types, it won't sort - instead, it tells me that a routine deep within Phobos is not nothrow (?)

```
B:\lib\D\dmd2\windows\bin\..\..\src\phobos\std\range\package.d(7189): Error: 'std.range.SortedRange!(RangeT!(Array!(MyInt)), "a < b").SortedRange.dbgVerifySorted' is not nothrow
B:\lib\D\dmd2\windows\bin\..\..\src\phobos\std\algorithm\sorting.d(982): Error: template instance std.range.assumeSorted!("a < b", RangeT!(Array!(MyInt))) error instantiating
main.d(21):        instantiated from here: sort!("a < b", cast(SwapStrategy)0, RangeT!(Array!(MyInt)))
```

Minimum example below. The first `sort` (an auto-generated standard array of two values) sorts fine. The other `sort` calls fail with the above compiler errors. Building with DMD2 from VS Community 2015, I can't find a compiler version identifier but this was downloaded only yesterday.

```
import std.array;
import std.container.array;
import std.algorithm.sorting;

struct MyInt
{
    int data;

    int opCmp(MyInt o)
    {
        return data - o.data;
    }
}

int main(string[] argv)
{
    MyInt ami, bmi;
    Array!MyInt arr = [ ami, bmi ];

    sort([ami, bmi]);
    sort(arr[0..2]);
    sort(arr[]);
    sort(arr.opSlice());

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the bug in Phobos: [Issue #14981](https://issues.dlang.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14981)

It was fixed like a month ago, but changes haven't made it to a release yet. Probably will be available in 2.069.

As a workaround for now you can build your project in release mode.

Comment: That's quite annoying! I can get it to work in debug mode by converting to a standard array: `auto arr2 = std.array.array(arr[]); sort(arr2); arr = Array!MyInt(arr2);` but that's not at all ideal for performance or readability purposes... Thanks anyway!